# I generated a table combining 3 tables but the generated table shows all the data I need to display specific column

Tags: mysql

I have generated a query combining 3 tables but the generated table shows all the data I need to display specific column please provide me the format.

```
SELECT * 
from bmtc_student_application bs 
    inner join bmtc_carddetail bc on bc.studentapplication=bs id 
    inner join bmtc_applicant ba on ba.id=bs applicant_id 
where bs.status=4 
and bc.isactive='t' 
and bc.duplicateorroutechangepassissued='f' 
and bc.generateddata between '2021-11-01' and '2021-11-30'
```

Comment: If you can read it, then maybe we can help

Comment: `SELECT col1, col2` if all you want to see are those 2 columns

Comment: Or `SELECT bs.Col1, bc.Col1, ba.Col1 ...`

Comment: How can I use the same command to create a permanent table so that I can stop using the command everytime?  Iam a rookie please help. Please help me by providing the modified command

Comment: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * returns all columns from the joined tables just as you observed. To select specific columns, change your SELECT statement to something like this:

```
select bs.col1, bc.col2, ba.col3 
from bmtc_student_application bs 
inner join bmtc_carddetail bc on bc.studentapplication=bs id 
inner join bmtc_applicant ba on ba.id=bs applicant_id 
where bs.status=4 
and bc.isactive='t' 
and bc.duplicateorroutechangepassissued='f' 
and bc.generateddata between '2021-11-01' and '2021-11-30'
```